# Bundle connection with 'Strain'

Tags: complex-analysis, differential-geometry, complex-geometry, fiber-bundles, connections

I am working on exercise 15.14 of Roger Penrose's "A Road to Reality" (Section 15.8 Bundle curvature).

We will be working on a bundle $\mathcal{B}^{\mathbb{C}}$ where the base space is the complex plane $\mathbb{C}$ and the fibers are copies of $\mathbb{R}$. Informally speaking - and to make the bundle interesting - we want to introduce some form of stretch (formally, the transformation $v \rightarrow 2v$) as we go around the unit circle on the base space $\mathbb{C}$.

Let's start with a REAL function $\Phi = \Phi(z, \bar{z})$ on the complex plane $\mathbb{C}$ to represent our cross-section.

We can assign the following operator (acting on $\Phi$): $\nabla = \frac{\partial}{\partial z} -ik\bar{z}$ where $k$ is a real constant and $ik\bar{z}$ is to be thought of as the "correction term" due to the 'strain' of the bundle (scalar multiplication). In other words, $\nabla \Phi = 0$ would correspond to a "horizontal" cross-section.

> **Question:** What is the value of the scalar $k$ so that the "stretching factor" (over the unit circle $S^1$) is equal to exactly $2$?

Naively, what (I would think) that would entail would be to solve the following equation for $k$, (assuming $\Phi = 1$):

$$\int_{S^1} \nabla{\Phi} dz  = 2$$

which for $\Phi = 1$, it would be equivalent to

$$\int_{S^1} -ik\bar{z} dz  = 2$$

Or

$$2\pi k =2$$

Which yields $k = \frac{1}{\pi}$

The issue I am having is that I am not using the fact that $\Phi$ is a function of both $z$ and $\bar{z}$, so I feel like I am missing a $d\bar{z}$ integral term. Yet, I could not justify it, since the incremental change $\nabla{\Phi} dz$ seems to include all there is, if we think of the unit circle as parametrized by $z=e^{it}$ where $t$ ranges from $0$ to $2 \pi$.

Ultimately, I suspect the issue boils down to my incomplete understanding of the insistence that $\Phi = \Phi(z, \bar{z})$ is to be thought as a function of two $2$-dimensional but "related" inputs (namely, as a function from $\mathbb{C}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$), as opposed to a function of two $1$-dimensional inputs (namely, $\mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$) which is its intended visual representation.

What is the missing link here? Any insights would be highly appreciated (the exact answer to the problem is immaterial)

Comment: Are you familiar with [antiholomoprhic functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antiholomorphic_function) and decomposiiton of a general function into its holomorphic and antiholomorphic parts?

Comment: @EricTowers I am not. As far as I know, Penrose does not mention those either (unless we count his comment relating conjugation and reflection symmetries). Regardless, I am happy to investigate them further. Is then $ik\bar{z}$ antiholomorphic? What are the direct/relevant implications of that?

Comment: ${\partial (\mathrm{i} k \overline{z})}/{\partial z} = 0$ so the antiholomorphic part of $\Phi$ is killed by your operator $\nabla$, leaving no trace of it in the integrand.  This is a good thing, otherwise integrating around a circle in only one variable would not be sufficient -- $\Phi$ is a function from $\Bbb{C}^2$ to $\Bbb{R}$ so you would need to include a $\mathrm{d}\overline{z}$ piece in the integrand and integrate on a 2-surface (probably a [polydisc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polydisc)) in $\Bbb{C}^2$.

Comment: Thank you @EricTowers. $\Phi=1$ so both parts of $\Phi$ seem to be killed by the operator then? Or did you mean $ik\bar{z}$ instead of $\Phi$? In any case, I am not sure I follow, since I am not familiar with thinking of $\Phi$ as a function from $\mathbb{C}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, let alone do integration on it. Is there some explanation using first principles of complex analysis? Or perhaps an online reference I can look up? Most textbooks treat functions like $\Phi$ as $\Phi=\Phi(z)$.

Comment: I can recommend [Tasty Bits of Several Complex Variables](https://www.jirka.org/scv/) as a starter that has a clear exposition of treating $\Phi$ as a function of $z$ and $\overline{z}$.  Full disclosure: I'm in the same department as the author.

Comment: This is helpful thanks! So it looks like I need to consider Wirtinger derivatives. The 1-form for a regular real function (in 2 real variables) should be given by $df = \nabla_x f dx + \nabla_y f dy$. Similarly, for our function $\Phi$ we should have $d\Phi = \nabla_z \Phi dz + \nabla_{\bar{z}} \Phi d\bar{z}$. Where $\nabla_z$ is what I originally called just $\nabla$ and  $\nabla_{\bar{z}} = \frac{\partial}{\partial \bar{z}} - \bar{ik\bar{z}}$. Does that sound about right?

Comment: I think you are now on the right track.  Good luck!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the subtlety is in the "dual" character of the definition of the operator. On the one hand, it seems as if $\nabla = \frac{\partial}{\partial z} -ik\bar{z}$ is the "whole" operator. That would be true, if $\Phi$ was just a function of $z$

In actuality, since $\Phi = \Phi(z, \bar{z})$, the above operator is only the first ***component*** of what would be a two dimensional covariant operator.

In other words, the above is better written as: $\nabla_z = \frac{\partial}{\partial z} -ik\bar{z}$

The subscript is necessary because we also have another component in the operator, one that corresponds to the $\bar{z}$ variable. (Similar to how in the real case one can write the first component of the gradient as: $\nabla_x f = \partial_x f$). This is of course the reflection (see: conjugate - the two are after all related!) of what we did before, which means that:

$$\nabla_{\bar{z}} = \bar{\nabla_z}=\frac{\partial}{\partial \bar{z}} +ikz$$

From there, we can easily calculate the differential $1$-form via:

$$d\Phi = \nabla_z \Phi dz + \nabla_{\bar{z}}\Phi d \bar{z} = -ik\bar{z} dz + ikz d\bar{z}$$

Passing this onto the integral we get:

$$\int_{S^1} d\Phi = \int_{S^1} -ik\bar{z} dz + ikz d\bar{z} = 2k\pi + 2k\pi := 2$$

which means that $k= \frac{1}{2\pi}$

**Credits:** Huge thanks to @EricTowers for all the help and references! All typos and errors are my responsibility.